# How to determine if a BasicBlock is controled by a `if`

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, control-flow-graph

I want to use LLVM to analyze if a basic block is affected by a control flow of an `if`(i.e., `br` instruction). "A basic block `BB` is NOT affected by `br`" means that no matter which of two blocks the `br` goes to `BB` will be executed for sure. I use an example to briefly show what I want:

[image]

My current rule to determine if a basic block `BB` is affected is (if `true`, affected.)

```
¬(postDominate(BB, BranchInst->leftBB) && postDominate(BB, BranchInst->rightBB))
```

Since I can not exhaustively test the rule above to all possible CFGs, I want to know if this rule is **sound** and **complete**.

Thanks!

### Further question

I am also confused if I should use `dominate` rather than `postDominate` like (I know the difference between post-dominance and dominance, but which should I use? Both rules seems work in this example, but I am not sure which one will/won't work in other cases):

```
Dominate(BranchInst->leftBB, BB) || Dominate(BranchInst->rightBB, BB)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A block Y is *control dependent* on block X if and only if Y postdominates at least one but not all successors of X.

`llvm::ReverseIDFCalculator` in `llvm/Analysis/IteratedDominanceFrontier.h` will calculate the post-dominance frontier for you, which is exactly what you need. The "iterated" part isn't relevant to your use case, ignore the setLiveInBlocks() method.

I have not tested this at all, but I expect that something like this should do the trick:

```
  // PDT is the llvm::PostDominatorTree
  SmallPtrSet<BasicBlock *, 1> BBSet{block_with_branch};
  SmallVector<BasicBlock *, 32> IDFBlocks;
  ReverseIDFCalculator IDFs(PDT);
  IDFs.setDefiningBlocks(BBSet);
  IDFs.calculate(IDFBlocks);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the example above, the code would produce: `IDFBlocks` is empty, when `BBSet`=`entry` (the block contains the interested branch). But iterating all blocks and finding when `IDFBlocks` of the block contains `entry` works.

Comment: control dependent seems a little subtle. Since by definition, the block `if.then1` post-dominates neither successor (i.e., `if.then` and `if.end3`) of the branch, but it may still be affected by the branch (only when `config == true`). So I think maybe I can relax the definition to "if Y post dominates not all successors of X."

Answer (score 0):

The relation `control dependent` is transitive. Applying the definition to all the control-dependent-impacted block(s) iteratively is the right way.